# Net::HTTPNotFound for https://dashboard.stripe.com/login -- unhandled response

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments, mechanize-ruby

We need to retrieve access to the logs for our Stripe instance for a specific time period.  There isn't an endpoint in there API (grrrr) so we are trying a quick screen scrape, because the dashboard structures them quite nicely.

At this point though I can't even log into Stripe using Mechanize.  Below is the code I am using to log in

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true

starting_link = 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/login'

page = agent.get(starting_link)
login_form = page.form

login_form.email = email
login_form.password = pass

new_page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons[0])
```

The response I get from running this is:

```
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for      https://dashboard.stripe.com/login -- unhandled response
from /Users/Nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.4/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:316:in `fetch'
from /Users/Nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.4/lib/mechanize.rb:1323:in `post_form'
from /Users/Nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.4/lib/mechanize.rb:584:in `submit'
from (irb):21
from /Users/Nicholas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I tried logging into several other sites and was successful.  I also aliased the agent and handled the re-direct (a strategy mentioned in other questions).

Does anyone know what tweaks could be made to Mechanize log into Stripe?

Thanks much

Comment: Did you try to use POST instead of http GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

I would suggest using a browser engine like Selenium to get the logs data as that will be much simpler.

**Long Answer:**

Though your `mechanize` form submission code is correct, it is assuming the `Stripe` login form is being submitted using a normal `POST` request which is not the case.

The `Stripe` login form is being submitted using an `AJAX` request.

Here is the working code to take that into account:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true

starting_link = 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/login'

page = agent.get(starting_link)
login_form = page.form

login_form.action = 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/ajax/sessions'
login_form.email = email
login_form.password = password

new_page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons[0])
```

As you can see, simply setting the form's action property to the `AJAX` url solves your problem.

However, once you have logged in successfully, navigating around the site to scrape it for logs will not be possible with `mechanize` as it does not support `javascript`. You can check that by requesting the dashboard's url. You will get an error message to enable `javascript`.

Further, Stripe's dashboard is fully `javascript` powered. It simply makes an `AJAX` request to fetch data from the server and then render it as `HTML`.

This can work for you as the server response is `JSON`. You can simply parse it and get the required information from logs.

Upon further inspection(in Chrome Developer Tools), I found that the logs are requested from the url `https://dashboard.stripe.com/ajax/logs?count=5&include%5B%5D=total_count&limit=10&method=not_get`

Again, if you try to access this url using `mechanize`, you will run into `CSRF` token problem which is maintained between requests by `Stripe`.

The `CSRF` token problem can be solved using `mechanize` cookies but it will not be worth the effort.

I would suggest using a browser engine like Selenium to get the logs data as that will much simpler.

Comment: @NickErdenberger Your'e welcome. You can also upvote if you think this answers your question ;)